# Maven resource plugin doesn't filter out customized delimiters nested in ${}

Tags: java, maven, maven-resources-plugin

I have a properties file:

```
property.a=$[value]
```

I am using maven-resources-plugin with filtering on this property file enabled in order to substitute build variables in there:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <delimiters>
            <delimiter>$[*]</delimiter>
        </delimiters>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Everything works flawlessly, until `$[*]` token is not nested into `${*}` one, like below:

```
property.a=${VALUE:$[value]}
```

Assuming `value=XXX` in Maven properties, I expected to get:

```
property.a=${VALUE:XXX}
```

However, Maven resources plugin doesn't substitute `$[value]` in there, leaving filtered contecnts as-is. I tried enabling `supportMultiLineFiltering` but it changed nothing. It feels like despite `<delimiters>` option is set explicitly, plugin treats `${*}` as a valid delimiter either, and tries to filter it, without success.

How should I configure maven resources plugin so that it filters the property file contents as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just realized I missed a configuration option in maven resource plugin, designed specially for controlling default delimiters - `useDefaultDelimiters`, which is true by default. The configuration below solved the issue:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <delimiters>
            <delimiter>$[*]</delimiter>
        </delimiters>
        <useDefaultDelimiters>false</useDefaultDelimiters>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```